Ordinal Regression in Python
I am dealing with a classification problem. The label comes from a continuos variable, which has been splited into 4 segments. Each of these segments represents a class.
I have tried several classification algorithms such as CatBoost and XGBoost to do so.
Recently I have known about ordinal regression, which seems to suit my problem.
Which algorithms and Python libraries have helped you the most to solve this problem? Have ordinal regression algorithms reported performance improvements for your tasks when compared to typical classification algorithms?
